# Azure DevOps extension project name returns externalContentHost512

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to get the name of the project in my web extension, launched from the work items context menu.

I am using the below code:

```
var projectPageService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
var projectInfo = await projectPageService.getProject();
```

`projectInfo.name` always returns `externalContentHost512` instead of the actual project name.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are samples [azure-devops-extension-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample)

And get [project name sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/blob/master/src/Samples/Hub/OverviewTab.tsx)

```
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
import { CommonServiceIds, IProjectPageService } from "azure-devops-extension-api";
const projectService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
const project = await projectService.getProject();
```